# angular ui-router state issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently trying to set up routes in my angular application.
I have these states:

```
.state('pet', {
  url: '/pet/:petId',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/profile.html',
  controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
})
.state('addPet', {
  url: '/pet/add',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
.state('editPet', {
  url: '/pet/:petId/edit',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
```

The problem is when I want to go on the 'addPet' state, angular is trying to call 'pet' state with 'add' as the ':petId' parameter.

So I tried to do it in a different way:

```
.state('pet', {
  url: '/pet',
  abstract: true
})
.state('pet.show', {
  url: '/:petId',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/profile.html',
  controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
})
.state('pet.add', {
  url: '/add',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
.state('pet.edit', {
  url: '/:petId/edit',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
```

and it doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order, keep **addPet** state before **pet** state

```
.state('addPet', {
  url: '/pet/add',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
.state('pet', {
  url: '/pet/:petId',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/profile.html',
  controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
})
.state('editPet', {
  url: '/pet/:petId/edit',
  templateUrl: 'scripts/views/profile/edit.html',
  controller: 'ProfileFormCtrl'
})
```

Comment: You are welcome @Mencls, you can always count on stackoverflow  :)